# Halting a method in a worker thread through a direct interruption

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, rest

I'm trying to implement a way to trigger a request for map overlay data (from an external web server) only when it seems necessary.

To do this i'm thinking about having screen touch events trigger a counter in an external thread, if the user hovers over a map area without touching the screen for about a second a request is sent.

Event flow would look something like this:

```
UI Thread      -down press-----release-----down---release---------------------->
                                  v          v       v
Worker Thread  -----------------start------stop----start---------------send---->
                                 timer======timer   timer==============request
                                        <1s                     1s
```

I'm having trouble getting the UIthread to stop the wait() call in a method and throw an InterruptionException, hence stepping out of the method body before it can execute the request. 
I basically want to just bypass any msg queue for the thread and have it stop execution instantly though I'm not sure this is possible. Am I on track here? My code for this is shown below:

```
public class ExtendedMapView extends MapView {

private final static int DOWN_PRESS = 1;
private final static int RELEASE_PRESS = 2;
private Handler countThreadHandler; 
private TouchThread touchMonitor ;

public ExtendedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    touchMonitor = new TouchThread();
    touchMonitor.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch(ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("TEST", "Touch Screen");
            touchMonitor.interrupt();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("TEST", "Touch released");
            countThreadHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(countThreadHandler,RELEASE_PRESS));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

private class TouchThread extends Thread {


    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        super.interrupt();
        Log.d("TEST", "Thread interrupted");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            Looper.prepare();
            countThreadHandler = new Handler() {

                                    @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what){

                        case DOWN_PRESS: 
                            runOnDown();
                            break;
                        case RELEASE_PRESS:
                            runOnUp();
                            break;                              
                    }
                };
            Looper.loop();
                Log.d("TEST", "thread started");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TEST", "thread not started");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void runOnUp() {
        Log.d("TEST", "count started");
        downPressed = false;
        try {
            Log.d("TEST", "Timer started");
                wait(1000); 
                            //SEND REST MSG BASED OFF RECIEVED MAP FILL CO-ORDS
            Log.d("TEST", "send Rest msg--------------------->");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TEST", "Received Interruption NIIICE");
        }

    }
}
}
```

I will keep reading and trying in the mean-time. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using the `postDelayed`method in the Handler instead of calling wait. So you would want to create a Runnable that will make your request and then in runOnUp you would do something like.  `myHandler.postDelayed(onUpRunnable, 1000)`  If then it comes time to cancel that request you just call `myHandler.removeCallbacks(onUpRunnable)`  I hope this helps!

edit: note this will only stop the runnable from starting if it hasn't already started. If it has started it will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks mate, this seems a really clean way to do this and is exactly what I was after. I actually managed to get it to work by calling interrupt. I'm going to go with your way though. Thanks again